# Xcode 5 crash on ios 5 device (ipad 1)

Tags: ios5, crash, xcode5

```
#0  0x0040b6f0 in cr_detectClasses ()
#1  0x33960ae8 in call_load_methods ()
#2  0x339608da in load_images ()
#3  0x2fe037d0 in dyld::notifySingle(dyld_image_states, ImageLoader const*) ()
#4  0x2fe0c85a in ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) ()
#5  0x2fe0d82c in ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) ()
#6  0x2fe04a40 in dyld::initializeMainExecutable() ()
#7  0x2fe08c1c in dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**) ()
#8  0x2fe032ce in dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*) ()
```

i have a project that i try to run on an ios 5 device my minimum deploy target is ios 5.0.
All frameworks i use are ios 5 compatible (so no need to put any on optional i guess?) but still it crashes on startup ( with the above stack trace )

ios6 + ios7 device work perfect.

Does anyone has any clue ?

Comment: Is cr_detectClasses yours?

Comment: no i think this all happens before the main ( i put a breakpoint in the main but it crashes before it gets to my breakpoint )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're including a framework or API that doesn't exist on iOS 5. Some steps for debugging:

1. Remove all unnecessary frameworks.
2. Remove all the code you can. Do you still get the problem if your program is nothing but a blank App Delegate?
3. If your bare-bones app still crashes on iOS5, it's a framework problem. Verify that all the frameworks really do exist on iOS 5.
4. If your bare-bones app works fine, add back code until you find the bit that causes the crash. Post the offending code so we can offer more specific suggestions.

Comment: removing them 1 for 1 i discovered the crittercism 4.3.0 was the one killing me :)

Comment: @jemmons I have crittercism v4_1_2 and in Crittercism.h it is said that i supports iOS 4.3+ it works fine in one app. But when i made a copy of the app and executed the copied app, it crashes in iOS 5 only. Then i set the Crittercism framework to optional and it runs fines. Why is it working fine in the first app in iOS 5 , 6, 7 whereas it crashes in new copy of the app only in iOS 5 and work fine in iOS 6 and 7. please help.